# How to configure Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls in web.config

Tags: asp.net, mono

I'm trying to add Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls to my web.config file. (This is necessary because I need to run the website on Mono and Mono doesn't yet support System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterModule)

The system.webServer section of web.config looks like this (simplified):

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="FriendlyUrls" type="Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls, FriendlyUrls" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
     <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Attempting to run the site (from Visual Studio) gets this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'FriendlyUrls' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I've checked the bin directory and Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll is there. Removing the FriendlyUrls line allows the app start just fine.

How do I add the FriendlyUrls module to web.config? Is this the correct way to work the Mono problem?

UPDATE
Based on Jester's suggestion I changed the type:

```
type="Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrl, Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls"
```

Now the error is:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.FriendlyUrl, Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls does not implement IHttpModule.
```

Comment: Did you try `type="Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls, Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls"`? Both the namespace and the assembly seem to have the prefix.

Comment: Thanks Jester. I've updated the question to reflect a new error message based on your suggestion.